# Reputation required to create my own Tag

Tags: support, reputation, privileges, tag-creation

I am quite confused now. I am not sure how much reputation I require to create a new tag.

From [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4396/please-increase-the-reputation-required-to-create-tags)  I came to know that I need 250 points to create my own Tag. But I already have the sufficient points, but when I try to create a new tag I am getting a message that I need 1500 rep points. Can anyone clarify this.

Comment: +1 for doing your research first. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating tags requires

- 1500 reputation on Stack Overflow (due to the # of users)
- 500 reputation on Meta Stack Exchange
- 300 reputation on Graduated Sites that have their custom design but that are still young and relatively small
- 150 reputation on public betas and graduated sites without a custom design

The question you linked to is years old and things have changed since then.

You can see the full list of privileges unlocked by reputation levels [here](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges).