# Reduce reputation requirement to create existing tags

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, reputation

Local creation of a tag on a Stack Exchange site [requires a certain number of reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95496/reputation-required-to-create-my-own-tag).

What about foreign/existing tags, i.e. tags which exist on other (or many) Stack Exchange sites? I feel the reputation required for creating those locally should be lower.

The immediate benefit is having more (relevant) tags on rather specialised questions which would otherwise have no or few tags, without adding to tag count chaos. The broader benefit would be that the various facets of a cross-cutting topic would be more easily discussed on multiple sites, while keeping track of what's going on.

As an example, we link [MediaWiki-related](https://stackexchange.com/filters/116580/mediawiki) questions [from the official MediaWiki website](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Communication#Forums) and that allows watching multiple sites at once, but I feel there are some more, where the topic is being discussed, that we don't know of because of the lack of a local tag. And this is a rather specific topic; there are way more interdisciplinary ones.

Comment: You really think a tag that exists on a cooking site should more easily cross over into a programming site or vice versa? Apple doesn't mean the same thing everywhere you know.

Comment: If anything I'd rather they *increase* it. All the crazy tags that get created as it is...

Comment: @RobertLongson, if I thought that a word/tag means the same everywhere, I would have proposed to make all local tags global. I only proposed to make it easier to create tags because if a tag is common there is an higher chance it makes sense as a tag. Definitely not a certainty.

Answer (score 8):

We have over 140 sites at the moment, spanning many different topics.

Most of which don't have much cross over - in particular not when it comes to meaning of tags. Even sites that do have cross over can have subtle (but important) differences in meaning and usage of tags with the same names.

I fail to see what the perceived problem here is or that having "shared" tags solves anything at all.

Comment: Did you open my [example](https://stackexchange.com/filters/116580/mediawiki)? Your premise that there is little cross over seems blatantly false to me: "MediaWiki" is an example of topic that can be discussed, with the same meaning, on many sites. I've just gone through the [full list](https://stackexchange.com/sites): I count 28 sites where it would be on topic, and 0 sites where it could mean something else. I'm sure there are many more examples.

Comment: I have looked through the list. 6 sites are represented, 3 of which only have a single mediawiki post, 2 have low numbers (under 10) and the last one has most (that's Stack Overflow). Even _if_ there would be such a tag on 28 sites (rather than the _actual_ 6), there are over 110 sites where there is no such cross over. The **meaning** of the tag is also (subtly) different from site to site, depending on the focus of the site. The effort required for making shared tags a reality is higher than the benefit.